# Is it good idea to recalculate available stock based on transaction table

Tags: mysql, database, math, orm

i tried to make Inventory system + pos, so far my problem is:

Tables:

```
Item
-Id
-Name

Buy
-Id
-Item_id
-qty

Sell
-Id
-Item_id
-qty
```

Is it good idea to recalculate current item qty everytime user want to know, by using this formula:

```
total_item_qty = sum(buy.qty) - sum(sell.qty)
```

what if there are more than thousand records of transaction of the item? it will be slow, right?

any suggestion for better solution please?

Comment: report wise, calculate on the fly.. should not really hurt the performance. however maybe you can limit your display within a timeframe or maybe handle it with an opening and close balances.

Comment: hello @maSTAShuFu, thanks for replying. is Open-closing balance you said is another table for qty checkpoint? like hard coded record of latest saved qty?

Comment: yes.. if you'd like annual checkpoint and making sure you've done your stocktake before making the checkpoint

Comment: ah, i see.. thanks for your sugestion @maSTAShuFu

Comment: Difficulty is that this is a matter of opinion, also with loads of questions - how many items, what level of throughput, type of environment (washers in factories get used twice as fast as they should do for some reason), accountability (one man businesses are less audited than large firms).

Comment: hundreds of item, 600+. any suggestion?